# How to display value of checkbox array key using post to another php page?

Tags: php

I am currently displaying a table with checkbox and the checkbox is displayed using while loop. For the value of each checkbox, I used value = "$key" . The problem that I am currently having now is, how can I post the value of the checkbox to another php page ?`

```
<?php $sm_sql = "SELECT * FROM submodule WHERE mod_id = '1'";
            $sm_res = DB_Query($sm_sql);

            while($sm_row = DB_FetchRow($sm_res)) {?>
    <tr> <?php 
        ?> <td><div align="center"> <?php echo $sm_row["submod_name"]; 
                ?></div>
        </td>
        <!-- key 1 = submod_create_id -->
        <td> <div align="center">
            <?php 
                $fi_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM finance_controlling WHERE staff_id =  '".$STAFF_ID."'");
                <?php 
                $fi_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM finance_controlling WHERE staff_id =  '".$STAFF_ID."'");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fi_sql))
                {
                    foreach($row as $key => $value)
                    {
                        if($key == $sm_row["submod_create_id"])
                        {
                            if($value == '1')
                            { ?><input type=checkbox checked="checked" name="$key" id="$key"> <?php
                                print $key; //it prints out the correct key

                            } else { ?><input type=checkbox name="$key" id="$key"> <?php
                                print $key;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            ?>
```

Above are my checkbox in Module_Form.php.
Below are Summary.php page where the value of the checkbox should be displayed on.

```
    if ($_POST["Submit"] == "Review Risk")
    {       

        $a = $_POST['fi_pp_c']; echo $a;

    }?>
```

The problem now is that the checkbox value are not passed to another page. Ive tried json_encode but there are still no value displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few thing I feel should be addressed here.

First up: Prepared statements
Having raw SQL in your PHP code which just inserts variables inside some quotes is dangerous. It might be ok for your current use case, but in future if this changes, it is all too easy for a developer to just make `$STAFF_ID` a `$_POST['varName']`, which immediately introduces SQL injection.

Please take some time to read up on prepared statements and stored procedures in SQL/PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Second up: HTML attribute values

This is ok and it is valid HTML, however, I'd suggest it is good practice to include all attribute values in quotes, so that if there are spaces in values, they are correctly interpreted. This is clearly not going to happen with the type attribute but it does make code easier to read and to process using more primitative parsers, if it were:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="<?= $key ?>" id="<?= $key ?>">
```

As to the original question: have you enabled debugging? Primatively you can do this by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your PHP file.

The issue I suspect you are facing is that is the checkbox is not checked, then there is no value for the key with the same name passed in the HTTP POST request.

For example, if you have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" />
```

And that checkbox is unchecked when the form is submitted, then in PHP `$_POST['myCheckbox']` is null.

So the solution is to check whether these fields are null, e.g.:

```
if(isset($_POST['myCheckbox'])) {
    $a = $_POST['myCheckbox'];
    echo $a;
}
```

I generally think this is a gap in protocol, and that unchecked checkboxes should be submitted in forms with a value of 0, but ho hum!

Comment: Thank you for your help. It did works when i add <?php ?> for the attributes :)

Regarding the issue to check the value ,  i did the same as yours before you even suggested but the value still nit being displayed :( 

*That is the most direct way to check but i wonder why T.T

Comment: and yess, i just realized that my main issues is that the checkbox is not checked ..

Comment: It's okay, Ive found my mistake already. its that there are some attribute that i didnt put <?php ?> .

Thank you so much for your answer. it helps a lot in reminding me what i missed!

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
?><input type=checkbox checked="checked" name="$key" id="$key"> <?php
```

you closed your PHP tag and reopened it after the HTML.

You need to reopen it to print your $key in the name and id parameters. As it is, it`s only treated as text. The browser just thinks that the id and name attributes are "$key".

```
?><input type=checkbox checked="checked" name="<?= $key ?>" id="<?= $key ?>"> <?php
```

and here :

```
} else { ?><input type=checkbox name="<?=$key ?>" id="<?= $key ?>"> <?php
```

This would solve your current problem, as long as the "name" of the checkbox is "fi_pp_c" otherwise, it will be stored in whatever is named the checkbox.

You can just `var_dump($_POST);` to check where you data is stored if you still have issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works this way. The value can be sent to another page already. However, if i check the unchecked box and submit, it cannot be read as checked. 

For example, i check box A and submit. but it still be read as unchecked. I did it like i used to do it but Im not sure what is the matter this time.

Comment: It's okay, Ive found my mistake already. its that there are some attribute that i didnt put <?php ?> .

Thank you so much for your answer. it helps a lot in reminding me what i missed!